# Where does Cloudera Manager store its configuration?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, alerts, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to track down an issue where email alerts are being sent from Cloudera Manager to an incorrect email address. We've corrected the email address in the Cloudera UI under "Alerts: Mail Message Recipients" and restarted the entire cluster a few times, but the messages are still being sent to the old incorrect addresses. Could someone detail the chain through which these alerts are passed?

Comment: It's stored in a database like MySQL or postgresql by default. You can configure it to use a different DB but otherwise it runs one locally.

Comment: Thanks, Sean. Ours must be in postgreSQL. Can you post this as an answer so I can tag it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Moving from comment.)* It's stored in a database like MySQL or postgresql by default. You can configure it to use a different DB but otherwise it runs one locally.